# How can I remove "Red Hat Network Code" from the RedHat?

Tags: linux, redhat, licensing, subscription

The question is: How can I remove "Red Hat Network Code" from the system and what this "Network Code" actually is?

The background of this question is related to the RedHat subscription as according to the official FAQ:
You can still use RedHat without a subscription if you remove all copies of Red Hat Network Code.
https://lists.openshift.redhat.com/renew/faq.html#6

However this question is not about am I allowed to do so or not, or why I would like to do so. The question is: what is the "Red Hat Network Code" and how to remove it? Does somebody know?

Comment: The only thing I can find is people speculating about what it is, no definitive answer. This may be something only your account manager can answer.

Comment: The Red Hat Network Code is all the code you got from Red Hat. If you want to run legally, without a support subscription to Red Hat, use CentOS or Fedora.

Answer (score 6):

The easiest way to solve this problem is to run CentOS or Fedora, rather than RHEL.  Anything along the lines of walking the filesystem using `sed` is a path of madness.